# SQL ACCESS 2010 Top 80 Percent by Group

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm trying to to calculate the top 80 percent of a time value per a unique identifier, so I need to group by that identifier. To which I am having trouble since the table I'm working with has 15 million records. A query that I found and used can manage to complete but crashes access once I try to scroll through the information.

```
SELECT TID, DATE, TRAVEL_TIME
FROM FH_2015
WHERE TRAVEL_TIME IN
(SELECT TOP 80 PERCENT TRAVEL_TIME
FROM FH_2015 AS A
WHERE A.TID = FH_2015.TID and A.DATE = FH_2015.DATE
ORDER BY TRAVEL_TIME ASC);
```

Comment: Would it help to say `Travel_time NOT IN (top 20 percent order by travel_time desc)`?

Comment: Are you nearing the 2Gb limit of database size? What version of ms-access?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming TID is a unique record identifier, this is all you should need:

```
SELECT TID, DATE, TRAVEL_TIME
FROM FH_2015
WHERE TID IN
(SELECT TOP 80 PERCENT
    TID
    FROM FH_2015
    ORDER BY TRAVEL_TIME DESC)
```

Note the `DESC` if you are actually looking for the top 80% of the TRAVEL_TIME.

And actually you could just do this:

```
SELECT TOP 80 PERCENT
TID, DATE, TRAVEL_TIME
FROM FH_2015
ORDER BY TRAVEL_TIME DESC
```

Comment: TID is not unique, which is why I am trying to group the 80th percentile by TID.

Comment: Does your table have a Primary key field? If it does use that to link the two instances of the table; you don't have to link by the same fields that you are trying to select. If it does not, my first advice is "never do that again" and my second advice is to set `TID` and `DATE` as indexed fields and see if that helps.

Comment: I'll try adding a primary key field next, I am just wondering if the script I'm using will allow me to group by TID to get the top 80.

Comment: Not the way it is written. I assume you want to use the `MAX(TRAVEL_TIME)` when you group by TID. It is doable but a bit more complicated than what your original script looks like.

Comment: I need to cut down the data by 80% in order to get the max value to get the 80th percentile. But so far I've not been able to figure out how to do the cutting.

Comment: Are you looking for the top 80% of all TRAVEL_TIME records (with potentially duplicate TID) or the top 80% out of the top TRAVEL_TIME for each TID?

Comment: I am looking for the 80th percentile of each TID, which is not unique. Which is why I am trying to group the top 80 percent by TID.

Comment: You totally lost me. Sorry. I can't understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: TID is not a unique field, as the same TID is shared with multiple travel times. Thus I want to get the 80th percentile of travel time per TID. Not the 80th percentile overall.